# HTML TABLE not forming

Tags: ajax, html

in the code below i want my data to be represented in a form of table but it is not showing in form of a table.
What should i do that my data comes in a table.

```
                $("#t1").append("<table>");
                $("#t1").append("<tr> <th> Book Name </th> <th> Publisher Name </th> <th> Publish Year </th> </tr>");
                for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                { 
                    $("#t1").append("<tr>" + "<td>" + e[j].bookName + "</td>" + "<td>" + e[j].publisherName + "</td>" + "<td>" + e[j].publishYear + "</td>" + "</tr>");
                }
                $("#t1").append("</table>");
```

my console shows something like this.

```
  <div id = t1>
   <table></table>
   <tr>...</tr>
   <tr>...</tr>
   .
   .
   .
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly bu you can so something like this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Add / Remove Table Rows Dynamically</title>
<style type="text/css">
    form{
        margin: 20px 0;
    }
    form input, button{
        padding: 5px;
    }
    table{
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    table, th, td{
        border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
    }
    table th, table td{
        padding: 10px;
        text-align: left;
    }
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".add-row").click(function(){
            var name = $("#name").val();
            var email = $("#email").val();
            var markup = "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='record'></td><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + email + "</td></tr>";
            $("table tbody").append(markup);
        });
        
        // Find and remove selected table rows
        $(".delete-row").click(function(){
            $("table tbody").find('input[name="record"]').each(function(){
             if($(this).is(":checked")){
                    $(this).parents("tr").remove();
                }
            });
        });
    });    
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name">
        <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email Address">
     <input type="button" class="add-row" value="Add Row">
    </form>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Select</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="record"></td>
                <td>Peter Parker</td>
                <td>peterparker@mail.com</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="button" class="delete-row">Delete Row</button>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//html//
     <div class="table-responsive"> 
    <table id="tbllogin" class='table table-hover table-bordered mt20'> 
    </table> 
    </div>



   //js//

    var arr = JSON.parse(r.d);
    $("#tbllogin").html(''); 
    $("#tbllogin").append("<thead><tr><th>UserName</th><th>Password</th><th>EmailId</th>" + "</tr></thead><tbody>"); 
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.Table.length; i++)
         { 
    var obj = arr.Table[i]; 
    $("#tbllogin").append("<tr>" + "<td>" + arr.Table[i].AUsername + "</td>" + "<td>" + arr.Table[i].APassword + "</td>" + "<td>" + arr.Table[i].AEmailId + "</td>" + "</tr>");
     }
             $("#tbllogin").append("</tbody>");
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.